# Contactless payment using NFC in Android

Tags: android, nfc, payment, tokenize, mastercard

I wanted to integrate contactless payment into one of my Android project using NFC. But I am not able to find any good resource for it. I have gathread basic information for NFC payment like

1. It uses APDU Command and responses to communicate
2. We'll need to tokenize card and pass the data to POS machine.

But still there is not any good respurce which guides me for APDU commands and how can I host my tokenized card for payment. Also I do not know how actual payment cycle works at POS machine.
Any help would be appriciated for this.